# Calculation using grouped data in Linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

So I have a table representing an business entity that has a one to many relationship with a table representing work items for that entity, the schema is basically this:

```
BusinessEntity
ID    Title   ...a bunch of other fields

WorkItem
ID    BusinessEntityID    WorkItemStateID

WorkItemState
ID    StateDescription
```

I am trying to write a Linq expression that returns an anonymous object with all the details of BusinessEntity and a field called PercentageComplete that details the number of work items associated with each entity that have a WorkItemStateID of 2

I have tried the following:

```
from e in db.BusinessEntity
     let wiAll = db.WorkItem.Where(x => x.BusinessEntityID == e.ID)
     let wi2Complete = db.WorkItem.Where(x => x.WorkItemStateID == 2 && x.BusinessEntityID  == e.ID)
     select new {
         BusinessEntityID = e.ID,
         PercentComplete = wiAll.Count() > 0 ? (int?)(Math.Round((Decimal)(wi2Complete.Count() / wiAll.Count()) * 100)) : null
     }
```

However this is not working, only ever giving me either a 1 or 0 as the PercentComplete. Im struggling to decipher the resulting SQL that is being generated though (the actual query is a lot more complex than this)

Is this even the right approach? Could I not use grouping  instead and if so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the percentage calculation expression to

```
(int?)(Math.Round(((Decimal)wi2Complete.Count() / wiAll.Count()) * 100))
```

It should do the trick. When you divide an integer by an integer the result is always an integer (0 or 1 in your case). If you cast the first value to decimal the result will be also a decimal value inside the range [0,1].

Comment: Based on the dataset the result should actually be anything between 1 and 100. None of the test data has a 1% completion, so there is something other than this going wrong

Comment: Sorry I doubted! That worked. I still need a moment to work out why exactly though!